# ajax do not work with www in URLs / php&html&ajax on linux sever

Tags: php, ajax

When I try  to test each ajax function on a php & html text it's works without `www` in URLs but not with `www`.

I'm on linux/centos server...what is my wrong? all links are internall without base url

Comment: Checkout your console logs first and find which type of error you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server doesnt have the `www` alias, therefore all you get is the 404 Not Found message.

Try enabling the `www` alias in your host configuration file for the specified site you're working. You can see more information about Apache's (assuming that you are using Apache as your Web Server) [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias).

**Hint:** Just place the following `ServerAlias www.your-domain.com` inside the VirtualHost tree.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding the http:// protocol.

E.g http:// www . domain . tld / file . ext

Without spaces obviously. Also just for information, Ajax requests cannot be made across domains.